# Eclipse RCP how to debug target platform?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

### Problem

I have included a lot of third party plugins in my RCP target platform. Most of them are provided as jar files.
Now I want to do some basic tasks, which are very easy on my own code, but which seems impossible on the target platform:

- see the included plugins
- seeing which files and classes are included in which plugin or jar
- opening files and class deinitions
- navigate to method and class definitions
- searching for strings
- setting break points

### Partitial Solution

As soon as a plugin is included as a library / Plugin-dependency in one of my own plugins, I can properly navigate through the Plugin as through normal libraries. Searching still seams problematic, but at least I can see the contents.

### Question

How do I perform these basic tasks on target platform plugins, if there not included by any of my own Plugins? And how do I search through included Plugins?

Answer (score 5):

Open the Preferences and go to Plug-in Development. Select the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' option.

Once this option is selected searches and things like 'Navigate > Open Type' will all include all the code in the target platform.